# scroll to the list's top when hide the modal

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, antd

I used `react-virtualized` to create a infinit list component and `antd` to create a modal component.List item bind the click event to show the modal.

hrer is demo's link: https://codepen.io/dingjs/pen/eRXZyw?editors=0010

1. Dont't scroll
2. Click list item (The modal will show)
3. Click close button of modal (Window will scroll to the top of list)
4. Scroll to top of window
5. Click the element out of list then close the modal(Everything is all righ)

The question was Occurred in the third step.

If list's header under the top of browser, window will scroll to the top of list.

Answer (score 0):

You did not *explicitly* say what your actual question is, but guessing from the title you want the window to scroll to top when the modal is closed. But that is so simple that I am thinking your actual question is something different...?

Put a

```
<div id="topOfList"></div>
```

at the start of the list, then

```
close = () => {
  this.setState({
    visible: false
   })
   document.getElementById('topOfList').scrollIntoView()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, I am sorry that there are some wrong places in the description of the problem, I added a part of the description, I hope you can provide some help.

Comment: Now it is making less sense than before. Are steps 1-5 describing what you *want* to happen? If in step 1 you do not scroll, the list will already be at the top and open/closing the modal changes nothing, so maybe step 1 should be "DO scroll"? What is the difference between step 3 "scroll to to of list" and step 4 "scroll to top of window"?